# Probability that your lineage continues indefinitely

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am interested in the chances that my genetic line continues forever given that I've have had one child.

For simplicities sake, let's assume that the number of children a given person can does not depend on time, sex, etc, and that my descendents never interbreed.

The probability that each person has n children is given by $p(n)$.

Let $p(n,i)$ be the probability that I have n descendents on the ith generation, with $p(n,1)=p(n) $.

What can we say about the general form of $p(n,i)$?

Under what conditions of p(n) is it true that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p(n,i))>0 $ (non zero probability that your genes will be passed on indefinitely)?

Intuitively, I would think that having the expected number of kids for each person being atleast one ( $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i*p(i) \geq 1$) would be a necessary and sufficient condition, but I do not have a proof.

Comment: Upon further research, I've found that this problem is identical to the [extinction problem for the Galton Watson Process][1]. 

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process